# Laravel 4 URL Rewrite

Tags: php, url-rewriting, laravel

I have a route that controls the current page user is in:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'v1'), function(){
    Route::resource('page', 'PageController', ['only'=>['index','show']]);
});
```

By the above code, it means that to go to homepage I need to type something like `http://localhost/public/v1/page`. So I need to make it to `http://localhost/public/v1` so I changed the above code to something like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'v1'), function(){
    Route::resource('/', 'PageController', ['only'=>['index','show']]);
});
```

That works only for `http://localhost/public/v1`, if i navigate to something like `http://localhost/public/v1/our-products` it will produce error says route not found. Is there any workaround for this (without using .htaccess rewrite)?

Additionally I would like to strip the `v1` in the link if possible, but the api code still there in the route, is it possible (again, without htaccess)? Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

Here's my `PageController`:

```
    <?php

class PageController extends MediaController { //MediaController extends BaseController

    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
    private $data = array();

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index() //this one for index/home page
    {
        $data = array();
        $data['data'] = null;

        $css_files = $this->addCSS(array('styles'));
        $plugin_files = $this->addJqueryPlugin(array('unslider'));

        $data['css_files'] = $this->addCSS(array('styles'));

        if(!empty($plugin_files) && isset($plugin_files)) {
            $data['css_plugin'] = $plugin_files['css_files'];
            $data['js_plugin'] = $plugin_files['js_files'];
        }

        $data['js_files'] = $this->addJS(array('app'));
        $data['title'] = 'Homepage - PT Anugerah Bhandala Sejati';

        $this->layout->content = View::make('page.home', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id) //this one for OTHER THAN home page (like news page or product page, so for example, the link "http://localhost/public/v1/our-products" logic will go here)
    {
        if($id === "our-products") {
            $data = array();
            $data['data'] = null;

            $css_files = $this->addCSS(array('styles'));
            $plugin_files = $this->addJqueryPlugin(array('unslider'));

            $data['css_files'] = $this->addCSS(array('styles'));

            if(!empty($plugin_files) && isset($plugin_files)) {
                $data['css_plugin'] = $plugin_files['css_files'];
                $data['js_plugin'] = $plugin_files['js_files'];
            }

            $data['js_files'] = $this->addJS(array('app'));
            $data['title'] = 'Our Products - PT Anugerah Bhandala Sejati';

            $this->layout->content = View::make('page.product', $data);
        }
        else 
            return "Page not found";
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you make a list of the routes that you would like to have? I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Manuel: What you see above is currently all my routes, i'm trying to make `/` as home page, `/our-products` as product categories page, `our-products/item1` as product specific page, `/news` as all news page, `/news/news1/title-of-the-news` as news specific page and perhaps other routes for ajax request later (no membership here)

Comment: could you post on your question what routes/urls you want and show your `routes.php` file here? i'm not sure but it must be the order of your routes..

Comment: Why did you add the `array('prefix' => 'v1')` part then?

Comment: @reikyoushin: the one you see in my question was all the code in my routes.php, all logic will be done in the `PageController` which i will add soon. @Manuel: API, possible enhancement in my controllers later. So i will just switch to another prefix like `v2` if I done major changes in my controller later.

Comment: i'm not sure but i think you can't put a '/' resource controller.. you must use v1 instead if you really like..

Comment: something like `Route::resource('v1', 'PageController', ['only'=>['index','show']]);` so you have a `http://localhost/public/v1` and a `http://localhost/public/v1/{resourceid}` routes auto generated

Comment: @reikyoushin: previous comment, exactly what i need, stupid of me not to think to make `v1` as resource itself, thank you very much :) (too bad there's no way to accept comments same as accept answers here)

Comment: i can put it as update on the answer though.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your comment:

> "What you see above is currently all my routes, i'm trying to make / as home page, /our-products as product categories page, our-products/item1 as product specific page, /news as all news page, /news/news1/title-of-the-news as news specific page"

what i understand is something like this..

On your `app/routes.php`

```
Route::resource('our-services', 'ProductsController', ['only'=>['index','show']]);
Route::get('news/{cat}/{title}', 'NewsController@single'); //news single post
Route::get('news', 'NewsController@index'); //news listings page
Route::get('/', 'HomePageController@index'); //home page
```

you just need to understand what you want first, then do things one step at a time..

*take note that this will not work as is, but i hope this will make things clearer for you*

---

UPDATE

If you still want to wrap them in v1, then:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'v1'), function(){
    Route::resource('our-services', 'ProductsController', ['only'=>['index','show']]);
    Route::get('news/{cat}/{title}', 'NewsController@single'); //news single post
    Route::get('news', 'NewsController@index'); //news listings page
    Route::get('/', 'HomePageController@index'); //home page
});
```

---

UPDATE 2

from another comment of yours, here's what i have come up:

```
Route::resource('v1', 'PageController', ['only'=>['index','show']]);
```

so you have a `http://localhost/public/v1` and a `http://localhost/public/v1/{resourceid}` routes automatically generated then..

Comment: yes, i realize with `Route::get` i can do just that, I just want to know if it possible without all those `Route::get` (as you see in my edit, `show` method will handle other than `/`routes)

Comment: using [Resource Controllers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) would mean you automatically add the two the resource routes with it.. if you want a custom route not in that list.. (in your case index and show) put it before the `Route::Resource` declaration since it may have a conflict (need more info on here)..